# How to call a function from external PHP file inside of WP plugin function

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to call a function from my external PHP file inside of my WordPress plugin when a post is being saved.

Here is what I'm trying:

*wordpress/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/functions.php*

```
// ...

function after_saving_post( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/my_dir/my_file.php';

    my_function();
}

add_filter( 'wp_insert_post', 'after_saving_post', 10, 3 );

// ...
```

*my_dir/my_file.php*

```
function my_function() {
    file_put_contents('test.html', 'Content');
}
```

The path to the external PHP file is correct, but the first function inside of my plugin doesn't call the second external function

How to resolve?

Comment: Do you have any errors? Did you tried `function_exists()` ?

Comment: How to resolve what? Are you absolutely sure `after_saving_post()` is being called? Because if it's called, the require_once and the function call would be executed. Either would raise an error if either file or function didn't exist.